# Fast pixel comparison against specific values

Tags: python, image, pixel

I am looking for a fast image pixel manipulation in Python. Is there any way to make this comparison with two rgb values faster?

```
img_new = np.ones(img_org.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 0
for i in range(img_org.shape[0]):
    for j in range(img_org.shape[1]):
        if img_org[i, j][0] == 0 and img_org[i, j][2] == 0:
            img_new [i, j] = 255
        else:
            img_new [i, j] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "vectorised" comparison in Numpy:

```
img_new = np.zeros(img_org.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
img_new[(img_org[:, :, 0] == 0) & (img_org[:, :, 2] == 0)] = 255
```

The expression `img_org[:, :, 0] == 0` takes the subarray of all first components of pixels (probably the red channel) and returns a Boolean array the same size as the image with `True` on pixels where the red channel is 0 and `False` otherwise.  The same is then done for the green channel, and we use `&` to find all pixels where both the red and the green channel are zero.  Then we use this mask to update the matching pixels to 255.

Also note that I replace `np.ones(...) * 0` by `np.zeros()`, and that we don't need the `else` branch in your code.  The pixels we don't touch are already zero.

Comment: Awesome speed and code improvement! Nice explanation, thanks a lot @Sven Marnach